# Iterate through iOS Core Data relationship

Tags: core-data, ios5

I am playing around with an app that keeps track of when people receive a publication. 
I have two core data entities, publication and person, which have to-many relationships to each other as each can have many of the other. 
Publication <<->> Person.

I am trying to iterate through the relationships so that if a person has received the publication the cell should be style check mark. If they haven't then it should be cell style plain. Here is what I have so far:

```
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Person *personForCell = (Person *) [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", personForCell.firstName, personForCell.lastName];


    NSArray *issuesForPersonArray = [personForCell.issues allObjects];

    if ([issuesForPersonArray count] != 0) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= [issuesForPersonArray count]; i++) {
        if ([issuesForPersonArray objectAtIndex:i] == km) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this it will display all persons as long as none have a relationship to this publication. But once I select their name I get this log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Here is the didSelectRow method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        // Reflect selection in data model
        Person *personSelected = (Person *) [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [publication addPersonObject:personSelected];


    } else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        // Reflect deselection in data model
        Person *personSelected = (Person *) [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [publication removePersonObject:personSelected];

    }

}
```

I'm sure I'm going about this all wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Figured it out. Here is what I used**

```
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Person *personForCell = (Publisher *) [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", personForCell.firstName, personForCell.lastName];

    NSMutableArray *issuesForPersonArray = [[personForCell.publication allObjects] mutableCopy];

    if ([issuesForPersonArray count] != 0) {

        for (Publication *publicationForPerson in issuesForPersonArray) {
            if (publicationForPerson == publication) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental design flaw in your code. You are using a UI element (the check mark) to inform your data model. This is very error prone and breaks all rules of the MVC (Model-View-Controller) programming paradigm.

Your basic approach about displaying the checkmark is ok. The data model is consulted to decide which UI element to use. However, it is not the best way to loop through your objects with an index. Also, looping is quite expensive when you scroll the tableview. Here is another approach:

*(I assume `km` is a reference to an instance of the publication entity in question.)*

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"ANY issues == %@", km];
NSArray *filteredArray = [[personForCell allObjects] 
   filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
if (filteredArray.count > 0) // check
else // uncheck
```

Stricty speaking there is still an iteration, but the framework is doing it for you, so you do not have to deal with those out-of-bounds errors.

When you want to change the relationship, you should use a similar method to retrieve this information:

```
if (filteredArray.count > 0) [personSelected removeIssuesObject:km];
else [personSelected addIssuesObject:km];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will change the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for sure. I'll give your answer a go with the predicate as well.

Comment: So when I try the predicate this is what I get:'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

Comment: '    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"ANY issue == %@", publication];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [[personForCell.pubs allObjects] 
                              filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (filteredArray.count > 0)
    {
        // check
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else{
     // uncheck
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }'

Comment: `issue` or `issues` ? To my mind, `issues` is indeed an NSSet (i.e. the attributes contained in the relationship).